# SQl equivalent Correlated query for ElasticSearch Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, correlated-subquery

I have a use case for writing an aggregation which if written in SQL can be achieved using correlated queries.

I have a index called listings where the properties/columns are ListDate, ListPrice, SoldDate, SoldPrice, OffMarketDate.

ListDate is not nullable, but SoldDate,SoldPrice, OffMarketDate can be nullable.

I want to aggregate stats from the above index based on the following requirement.

- I want to have monthly stats, which I see can be achieved by
  DateHistogramAggregation
- For each month from the
  DateHistogramAggregation, I want to find the listings as follows:
  Example: For Jan 2019, get all the listings where (ListDate< Feb 1st, 2019) and (SoldDate is null or SoldDate<Jan 1st, 2019) and (OffMarketDate is null or OffMarketDate< Jan 1st, 2019)
- Then run the aggregation function for those lists each month.

I appreciate any suggestions to implement this use case. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below details and info as how you can approach this problem:

### Mapping:

```
PUT listings
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "listDate":{
        "type": "date"
      },
      "listPrice":{
        "type": "long"
      },
      "soldDate":{
        "type": "date"
      },
      "soldPrice": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "offMarketDate": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've constructed the above mapping looking at your question.

### Sample Documents:

```
POST listings/_doc/1
{
  "listDate": "2020-01-01",
  "listPrice": "100.00",
  "soldDate": "2019-12-25",
  "soldPrice": "120.00",
  "offMarketDate": "2019-12-20"
}

POST listings/_doc/2
{
  "listDate": "2020-01-01",
  "listPrice": "100.00",
  "soldDate": "2019-12-24",
  "soldPrice": "122.00",
  "offMarketDate": "2019-12-20"
}

POST listings/_doc/3
{
  "listDate": "2020-01-25",
  "listPrice": "120.00",
  "soldDate": "2020-01-30",
  "soldPrice": "140.00",
  "offMarketDate": "2020-01-26"
}

POST listings/_doc/4
{
  "listDate": "2020-01-25",
  "listPrice": "120.00",
  "soldDate": "2020-02-02",
  "soldPrice": "135.00",
  "offMarketDate": "2020-01-26"
}

POST listings/_doc/5
{
  "listDate": "2020-01-25",
  "listPrice": "120.00"
}

POST listings/_doc/6
{
  "listDate": "2020-02-02",
  "listPrice": "120.00"
}
```

Note how I've not added the `soldDate` and `offMarketDate` in the docs 5 and 6 as that would be better option than having it with `null` value.

### Request Query:

So I've come up with the below query for your use-case.

Also for the sake of aggregation, let's say I've calculated the total `soldPrice` for the docs having

- `listDate` in the month of `Jan 2020` **AND**
- (`soldDate` either `null` **OR** `soldDate` before the month of `Jan 2020`) **AND**.
- (`offMarketDate` either `null` **OR** `offMarketDate` before the month of `Jan 2020`).

Below is the query:

```
POST listings/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "listDate": {
              "gte": "2020-01-01",
              "lte": "2020-02-01"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "soldDate": {
                    "lte": "2020-01-01"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "soldDate"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "offMarketDate": {
                    "lte": "2020-01-01"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "offMarketDate"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_histogram": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "listDate",
        "calendar_interval": "month"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_sales_price": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "soldPrice"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query above is very easily readable and self explanatory. I'd suggest reading about the below different queries which I've made use of:

- [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)
- [Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)
- [Field Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) to verify if field exists or not.
- [Data Histogram Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html)
- [Sum Metrics Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html)

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 3.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "listings",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 3.0,
        "_source" : {
          "listDate" : "2020-01-01",
          "listPrice" : "100.00",
          "soldDate" : "2019-12-25",
          "soldPrice" : "120.00",
          "offMarketDate" : "2019-12-20"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "listings",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 3.0,
        "_source" : {
          "listDate" : "2020-01-01",
          "listPrice" : "100.00",
          "soldDate" : "2019-12-24",
          "soldPrice" : "122.00",
          "offMarketDate" : "2019-12-20"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "listings",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "listDate" : "2020-01-25",
          "listPrice" : "120.00"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_histogram" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1577836800000,
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "total_sales_price" : {
            "value" : 242.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As expected, documents `1,2 and 5` are showing up with the correct aggregated sum of `soldPrice`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also welcome to SOF, if you think your query has been resolved, feel free to `upvote` the answer by clicking on the `up arrow` key you see at the start of the answer and/or `accept` the answer by clicking the `greyed out tick mark` that is just under it.

Comment: Thank you Opster ES Ninja - Kamal. This is a great answer.

It works for a given month. I see you are Querying the listings first for January month, and adding aggregation for that month,

My question is slightly beyond that. Lets say that the data spans for whole months of year 2019. I want a query that automatically spans for all 12 months of 2019, and for each month, aggregate the data based on the logic I provided and run aggregation. I don't want to call 1 query per month from my application.